# Importing Python files into each other on a web server

Tags: python, sqlite, web

Using CGI scripts, I can run single Python files on my server and then use their output on my website.

However, I have a more complicated program on my computer that I would like to run on the server. It involves several modules I have written myself, and the SQLITE3 module built in Python. The program involves reading from a .db file and then using that data.

Once I run my main Python executable from a browser, I get a "500: Internal server error" error.

I just wanted to know whether I need to change something in the permission settings or something for Python files to be allowed to import other Python files, or to read from a .db file.

I appreciate any guidance, and sorry if I'm unclear about anything I'm new to this site and coding in general.

FOLLOW UP: So, as I understand, there isn't anything inherently wrong with importing Python files on a server?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look in the log of your server to find out what caused the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an extensive error message by adding the following lines at the beginning of your CGI script:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```